# Help to create an array

Tags: list-manipulation

Can anyone please help me out? I want to create a $256 \times 256$ matrix with zero elements on the upper left hand and ones elements on the lower right end.

Answer (score 10):

```
Reverse[UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {256, 256}]]]
```

Slightly smaller for legibility:

```
Reverse[UpperTriangularize[ConstantArray[1, {5, 5}]]]//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Two more possibilities:

```
With[{n = 256}, HankelMatrix[UnitVector[n, n], ConstantArray[1, n]]]

With[{n = 256}, Normal[SparseArray[{{j_, k_} /; j + k >= n + 1 -> 1}, {n, n}]]]
```

Comment: `HankelMatrix` is the fastest and most memory-efficient method from all answers in this thread, while `SparseArray` is the slowest and takes the most memory.

Answer (score 4):

```
n = 256
PadLeft@Internal`PartitionRagged[ConstantArray[1, n*(1 + n)/2], Range[n]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short version using `DiamondMatrix`:

```
Take[DiamondMatrix[4], 5, 5]
```

[image]

For $256 \times 256$ matrix one can use:

```
Take[DiamondMatrix[255], 256, 256]
```

Answer (score 2):

A few more alternatives:

```
Unitize[HankelMatrix @ 5][[-1 ;; 1 ;; -1, -1 ;; 1 ;; -1]] // MatrixForm
Reverse /@ Reverse @ Unitize @ HankelMatrix @ 5 // MatrixForm
PadLeft @ Unitize @ Range @ Range @ 5 // MatrixForm
```

all give

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: also `Table[1, #] & /@ Range@5 // PadLeft`

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{n = Range @ 256}, Reverse @ Table[UnitStep[n - i], {i, 256}]]; // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.000244, Null} *)
```

**Relatively small example:**

[image: example]